# Azure B2C send user invitation

Tags: .net, azure, azure-ad-b2c

I need to send invitations from my dotnet code. So I followed this link: https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/invite

My problem is the management of the certificate. I do not want to generate certifcat locally and have it to import it in azure. How? I have seen that in the personalized strategies secrets and kets can be generated. How to do and then use them in my code to sign my token

Answer (score 0):

For this to work, you **have** to create a certificate.

It can be self-signed. You import this into the B2C tenenat.

However, you do not have to host the metadata endpoint in a website.

You can host it in [B2C itself](https://medium.com/the-new-control-plane/hosting-the-id-token-hint-well-known-endpoint-in-azure-ad-b2c-itself-1c27be147613).

Comment: It is precisely this issue of certificate that bothers me because it must be renewed every year. He offered us to directly generate strategy keys but I find no example of using them in code to sign a token for example

Comment: The B2C piece that verifies the signature is coded for certificates only.

Comment: So if I understand I have to go through a certificate that I generate and that I have to import and therefore change every year. 
I can’t use what azur offers is signature strategy key generation

Comment: This is B2C not Azure AD. So you can't use Key Vault etc. The certificate can be valid for any length of time. That's up to you as is the way you generate it.

Comment: So why do we offer the opportunity to create a strategy key if we can’t use them in our code afterwards

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/create-custom-policies-for-azure-active-directory-b2c